Multiprocessing python on NFS gets 'No such file or directory' from os.cwd()
I've been troubleshooting a test case on an EL9 environment which behaves differently in an EL7 environment.
It's specifically:

On an NFS mounts.
Occurs on our EL9 systems (5.14.0-362.18.1.el9_3.x86_64). Does not occur on any of our older Centos 7 systems (3.10 kernel various versions).
In a subdirectory. (Doesn't happen in a 'top level' mount).
The code frequently 'breaks' with os.cwd() returning 'no such file or directory'.

Reproduced on:

5.14.0-427.el9.x86_64 (Alma)
5.14.0-362.24.1.el9_3.x86_64 (Alma)
5.14.0-362.18.1.el9_3.x86_64 (Alma)
5.14.0-362.8.1.el9_3.x86_64 (RHEL)

Example reproduction code:
#!/usr/bin/python3 -u

import os
import multiprocessing
import time

if __name__=="__main__":
    multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")

    count = 0
    while True:
        try:
            os.getcwd()
            pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
            pool.close()
            pool.terminate()
            count += 1
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed after {count} iterations")
            print(e)
            break

I'm at something of a loss to understand quite what's going on here, and quite why it fails.
It seems to be connected to pool.terminate() as if you add even a short (0.05) sleep before that, the problem stops occurring (at least, wasn't reproducible in 'sensible' amounts of time, where the above fails in <10 iterations).
And interestingly the cwd stays inconsistent:
build-2[myuser]:[~/python_race]$ ./simple.py 
Failed after 2 iterations
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
build-2[myuser]:[~/python_race]$ ./simple.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1362, in _path_importer_cache
KeyError: '.'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./simple.py", line 4, in <module>
    import multiprocessing
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 982, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 925, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1423, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1392, in _get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1364, in _path_importer_cache
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1340, in _path_hooks
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1610, in path_hook_for_FileFinder
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1486, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

This seems to 'recover' with a chdir, or waiting for what I assume is an NFS cache expiry interval.
We've picked this up due to some of our tests failing on the 'new version' on a more simplistic:
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")

while True:
    multiprocessing.Pool(10)

But as mentioned - specific to NFS mounts in subdirs which we think might be because the struct dentry behaving a bit differently on root mounts.
But I was wondering if anyone could shed some insight into what might be going wrong here? I'm at a loss to identify whether it might be fileserver, linux kernel, something within python, or... well, somewhere else entirely.
With rpcdebug enabled we appear to get:
Apr 24 11:58:47 build-2 kernel: NFS: release(lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
Apr 24 11:58:47 build-2 kernel: NFS: release(lib/libc.so.6)
Apr 24 11:58:47 build-2 kernel: NFS: release(locale/locale-archive)
Apr 24 11:58:47 build-2 kernel: NFS reply getattr: -512
Apr 24 11:58:47 build-2 kernel: nfs_revalidate_inode: (0:53/3834468196) getattr failed, error=-512
Apr 24 11:58:47 build-2 kernel: NFS: lookup(/python_race)
Apr 24 11:58:47 build-2 kernel: NFS call  lookup /python_race
Apr 24 11:58:47 build-2 kernel: RPC:       xs_tcp_send_request(168) = 0
Apr 24 11:58:47 build-2 kernel: NFS: release(bin/python3.11)

Edit:
Have also found it does not occur if you add a pool.join() prior to the terminate()

Not very helpful but it's clearly something to do with your environment. Your code runs ad infinitum without error on macOS

It's useful information - yes, I have a suspicion there's 'something' intersectional about NFS/EL9/Python here. Would you be able to let me know what kernel you're on?

macOS Sonoma 14.4.1 with Python 3.12.3

This isn't really an answer-answer, as much as confirmation that it is, in fact, a kernel bug, not a python issue - it just so happens that python was an easy way to 'trigger' it.
Logged with RedHat: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RHEL-35853
If anyone's hitting the same problem, we found that adding:
pool.join()

into the code prior to pool.terminate() seems to stop it occurring, but give the issue is in kernel space, we're not confident that it's anything more substantive than "just" a short delay in the code, which masks the implicit race condition.
We've found that a sleep(0.05) likewise seems to prevent it happening, presumably for similar reasons, as there's no way userspace should be able to invalidate the directory entry caching in the first place.
